# Does it matter if blockquotes contain quote characters for SEO or accessibility?

Tags: seo, html, accessibility

If I have a block quote

```html
<blockquote>
    <p>“Time is an illusion. Lunchtime doubly so.”</p>
</blockquote>
```

Does it matter or impact seo if I do or don't include  quote characters `“`, `”`with the quote?

```html
<blockquote>
    <p>Time is an illusion. Lunchtime doubly so.</p>
</blockquote>
```

Will blockquotes without quote characters be interpreted in exactly the same way?

Answer (score 2):

In terms of SEO, this should make no difference whatsoever.

Search engines rank content based on many factors, but whether the content is wrapped in quotes is not something that matters.

Comment: How about for accessibility?  They used that tag as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/typography/#blockquotes), [Foundation](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/typography-base.html#blockquotes), and [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-blockquote-element.html) all don't use literal quotes. I'd say leave them out.